# Variation number of tw0 digit numbers in array of 5 without repetition and order

Tags: statistics

How to calculate variations of 2 digit numbers [00-99] in the array of 5 for each variation? Order and repetition should not be considered.

variation pattern : {--,--,--,--,--}

ex:

variation 1 = {01,02,03,04,05}

variation 2 = {01,02,03,05,04} // Invalid variation. Already exist with different order.

variation 3 = {01,02,03,04,06}

variation 4 = {34,56,73,34,98} // Invalid variation. Contains repetition(34).

.

.

.

---

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/35180/166912) answer for the non-repeatable variations but how to apply non-order considered variations to this formula?

Thank you.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/35180/166912

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not considering order and repetition then what you are looking for is the typical [Combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination), this is, how to form groups of numbers from $0$ to $99$ taking those numbers in $5$.

Formally, $C^{100}_5 = \frac{100!}{5!(100-5)!} = 75287520$ possible arrangements.

---

If you take order in consideration then instead of a Combination you have a [Variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n) where each aforementioned group is permuted, so you will end up with a total of:

$\frac{100!}{(100-5)!} = 9034502400$ possible arrangements.

Comment: What if different orders are acceptable?

Comment: @Eftekhari: I have edited my answer to include ordering.

Comment: I think you have a typing mistake in the second part. It should be (100 - 5)!.

Comment: @Eftekhari: Yes you are right. It is always "n - k" where "n=100" and "k=5" so it is "(100-5)!". Fixed it.